# What am I doing wrong when using Solve ( Wolfram Alpha)

Tags: equation-solving, wolfram-alpha-queries

It is not because we do not interpreted correctly

WolframAlpha["Solve[64(!(*FractionBox[(x - *SqrtBox[(*SuperscriptBox[(x), \
(2)] - 1)]), (x + 1)]) !(*SuperscriptBox[()), \
(2)])-25(1-!(*FractionBox[SqrtBox[(x - 1)], (x + 1)]) \
!(*SuperscriptBox[()), (2)])+9==0,x]"]

[image]

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: It appears that Alpha is misinterpreting your query, since it ends up being expressed in the `Box` formatting language. Furthermore, it seems to me from the screenshot that you are using desktop *Mathematica * to carry out a Wolfram|Alpha query expressed as a *Mathematica* function. I can't quite follow the logic in doing that: why don't you just run the `Solve` command directly?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
=Solve[64((x-Sqrt[x^2-1])/(x+1))^2-25(1-Sqrt[x-1]/(x+1))^2+9==0, x]
```

and this

```
WolframAlpha["Solve[64((x-Sqrt[x^2-1])/(x+1))^2-25(1-Sqrt[x-1]/(x+1))^2+9==0,x]"‌​]
```

solve immediately.

Note: One reason for using WolframAlpha to handle some calculations is that you can sometimes see the steps involved, see additional information, make use of curated data in the calculation, etc.

After experimenting, WolframAlpha does not appear to understand FractionBox or SuperscriptBox or any other "two dimensional" "desktop published" input. That is the reason your query failed. Use "one dimensional" input form and you get your answer.

If you just must "desktop publish" your equations, to use square root symbols, numerators stacked over denominators, etc. then Put all that inside

```
=InputForm[...your two dimensional equations...]
```

which will undo the publishing format and mostly put your math into a form that WolframAlpha will understand.